# How to remove "Hover" in dropdown mega menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, megamenu

I have an dropdown mega menu.It works fine as per our requirment.I would like to know how to open dropdown menu when I click on Menu instead of "hover".Please check the below code and advise how to do this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container"><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Obaju logo" class="d-none d-md-inline-block"><img src="img/logo-small.png" alt="Obaju logo" class="d-inline-block d-md-none"><span class="sr-only">Obaju - go to homepage</span></a>
      <div class="navbar-buttons">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle search</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button><a href="basket.html" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown menu-large"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="200" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Men<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
              <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <h5>Clothing</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-3">
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">T-shirts</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Shirts</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Pants</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <h5>Shoes</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-3">
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Trainers</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Sandals</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Hiking shoes</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="category.html" class="nav-link">Casual</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropdown menu disappears when I try to hover it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360032/dropdown-menu-disappears-when-i-try-to-hover-it)

Comment: No I would like to remove hover to open sub menu in dropdown. I Would like to open sub menu in dropdown when I click on menu only not as hover